# Howto deploy python applications inside corporate network

Tags: python, deployment, python-3.x, setuptools

First let me explain the current situation:

We do have several `python` applications which depend on custom (not public released ones) as well as general known packages. These depedencies are all installed on the `system python` installation. Distribution of the application is done via `git` by source. All these computers are hidden inside a corporate network and don't have internet access.

This approach is bit pain in the ass since it has the following downsides:

- Libs have to be installed manually on each computer :(

How to better deploy an application? I recently saw `virtualenv` which seems to be the solution but I don't see it yet.

`virtualenv` creates a clean `python instance` for my application. How exactly should I deploy this so that usesrs of the software can easily start it?

Should there be a startup script inside the application which creates the `virtualenv` during start?

The next problem is that the computers don't have internet access. I know that I can specify a custom location for packages (network share?) but is that the right approach? Or should I deploy the zipped packages too?

Would another approach would be to ship the whole python instance? So the user doesn't have to startup the `virutalenv`? In this python instance all necessary packages would be pre-installed.

Since our apps are fast growing we have a fast release cycle (2 weeks). Deploying via `git` was very easy. Users could pull from a `stable` branch via an update script to get the last release - would that be still possible or are there better approaches?

I know that there are a lot questions. Hopefully someone can answer me r give me some advice.

Comment: These are two independent issues, aren't they? (A) How does a client (or the central server) determine when to upgrade one or more applications? (B) How to package and deliver an application. For (A) maybe you could rephrase to make clearer what your client/server or author/user model looks like. And what do you mean by "don't have internet access"? Is that relevant to the question? If the update server and all client computers are within the network, they have all the visibility they need, don't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pip` to install directly from `git`:

```
pip install -e git+http://192.168.1.1/git/packagename#egg=packagename
```

This applies whether you use `virtualenv` (which you should) or not.

You can also create a `requirements.txt` file containing all the stuff you want installed:

```
-e git+http://192.168.1.1/git/packagename#egg=packagename
-e git+http://192.168.1.1/git/packagename2#egg=packagename2
```

And then you just do this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

So the deployment procedure would consist in getting the `requirements.txt` file and then executing the above command. Adding `virtualenv` would make it cleaner, not easier; without `virtualenv` you would pollute the systemwide Python installation. `virtualenv` is meant to provide a solution for running many apps each in its own distinct virtual Python environment; it doesn't have much to do with how to actually install stuff in that environment.

Comment: Good info. Learned something here. It does not yet answer the part of the question how to bridge the missing "internet connection". Maybe the question must be elaborated to understand the full needs of the asker?

Comment: @cfi: The OP said they are in internal network. That's why the example of getting stuff from a git repository in 192.168.1.1.